# Fancybox is taking 2 clicks to open dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, fancybox

Using JQuery, I am loading a div from an external HTML page into fancybox and am building the link using variables.  It is taking two clicks to open it. The first, I believe, is only initiating it. But I don't know how to fix it. Is there a better way to be doing this?

**The HTML is here:**

```
<a class="BannerVideoAwesome fancybox" id="series900" border="0"   href="/mkting/Videos/Speakers.html"><img src="/images/titles/CM/series-speakers-video.jpg" border="0"  align="left" /></a>
```

**The jQuery is here:**

```
$('a.BannerVideoAwesome').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var grabVid = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    vidObject = url + grabVid;
    var vidContents = vidObject.html();
    alert(vidContents);
    $.fancybox({
            //'href': url,
            'content':'vidContents'
                     });
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help someone can give me. I have been struggling with this for days.

Comment: Is this happening across all browsers?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510194/why-does-fancybox-require-two-clicks-activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the title of your post is a little bit misleading. Anyway, if I understood right, you just want to load a partial content (DIV) from an external html file into fancybox.
In your example, the file episodeSpeakers.html contains a DIV with ID='series900'

```
<div id="series900">selected content</div>
```

If the above is correct, then you don't need to use jQuery live(), but binding fancybox to a click() and use ajax and dataFilter to select the content.

With the same html, this script should do the trick:

```
$("a.BannerVideoAwesome").click(function() {
var grabVid = "#"+$(this).attr('id');
$.fancybox(this,{
 'type': 'ajax',
 'ajax': {
   dataFilter: function(data) {
   var vidContents = $(data); 
   vidContents = $(grabVid, vidContents); 
   return(vidContents); 
  } // datafilter
 } // ajax
}); // fancybox
return false;
}); //click
```

or you may use

```
$("a.BannerVideoAwesome").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
.
.
```

instead of

```
return false;
```

---

**IMPORTANT** : Due to some cross-browser issues, don't use the dataFilter solution above.
It would be better to use the fancybox's inline method, adding the partial content (from the external html file) into a hidden DIV within your calling html document and then move it from there into fancybox. It requires (of course) to add such DIV. e.g.:

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="fancyContent"></div>
</div>
```

Then use this script:

```
$("a.BannerVideoAwesome").click(function() {
var grabVid = "#"+$(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
 type: "GET", // default
 dataType: "html",      
 cache: false,                      
 url: this.href,
 success: function (data) {
  $("#fancyContent").html(grabVid ? $("<div>").append(data).find(grabVid) : data);
  $.fancybox({
   'href': "#fancyContent",
   'onCleanup': function() {
     var fancyContent = this.href;
     $(fancyContent).unwrap().empty();
   } // onCleanup 
  }); // fancybox
 } // success
}); //ajax
return false;
}); //click
```

that works on most browsers.
BTW, the onCleanup option fixes [this bug](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33/)

Comment: It turns out, I think the issue I was having had more to do with the content I was loading into fancybox, which was a video player from Limelight. I ended up initiating the player on page load, and then fancybox opened right up with this code: 
$('a.BannerVideoAwesome').live("click",function(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
 var grabVid = '#' + $(this).attr("id");
 //alert(grabVid);
 $.fancybox(this,{
      'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': { dataFilter: function(data) {
  
         return $(data).filter(grabVid)[0]}
 }
    });
});

Comment: I did test dataFilter and it doesn't work properly in all browsers. If I was you, I would test the code on different browsers, if you want true cross-browser compatibility of course.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change from **click** event into **mouseover**.

```
$('a.BannerVideoAwesome').live('mouseover', function(e){
...
```

Comment: In normal way fancybox works as soon as element been loaded. In your case you're assigning fancybox to an element only after click, what means that you have to click element again to launch fancybox after that you assigned in first click. So you need to assign it before you click an element, and in this case mouseover will work before click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.BannerVideoAwesome').live('click', function (event) {
    $.fancybox(this,{
        'autoDimensions': true,
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'ajax',
        'padding': 0
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```