# Fancybox + VideoJS - why 2 click to activate?

Tags: video, fancybox

After a search
[Why does fancybox require two clicks activate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510194/why-does-fancybox-require-two-clicks-activate)

however I still can't resolve the issue.

My file is located here

http://bitstream.ca/beta/#

Can any FancyBox experts tell me why it takes 2 clicks?

And also why I can't seem to get rid of the vertical scroll?

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the `.fancybox()` call on DOM ready, not on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $elt = $('div.jTscroller'),
        id = $elt[0].id,
        url = id + '.html',
        w = parseInt($elt.attr('w'), 10),
        h = parseInt($elt.attr('h'), 10);

    $elt.fancybox({
        padding: 2,
        height: h + 28,
        width: w + 23,

        autoScale: true,
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        openSpeed: 150,
        type: 'iframe',
        href: url,
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        closeSpeed: 250,
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            overlay: {
                speedIn: 750,
                opacity: 0.9
            }
        } //end helpers
    }) //end fancybox                
}); //end click
}); //end ready​​
```

The pesky scrollbars show because the `<body>` element of the page at `video1.html` has a user-agent default 8px margin applied to it. Add `margin: 0` to that element and you're good to go:

[image]

Comment: Thanks scrollbar issue resolved, but not the double click. Tried simply cutting and pasting your code above and all my values(id, url, w,h) are undefined.