# Fire fancybox function inside a onclick? Simulating the normal fire

Tags: jquery

This is a massive conundrum for me. I will explain in full.

I normally simply fire the fancyapps fancybox plugin like this...

```
$("a.gallery-thumb").fancybox({

    afterLoad   : function() {

        /* shtuff */

    }

});
```

But I need to pass a unquique varible when the `a.gallery-thumb` is clicked. This unique varible is generated using this...

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info) {

    var scrollPosition = info.scrollTop;

};
```

This `scrollPosition` unique varible is the current scroll position when my `a.gallery-thumb` is clicked.

So I need to then pass the `scrollPosition` variable into the fancybox function below.

```
$("a.gallery-thumb").fancybox({

    afterLoad   : function() {

        $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');   

    }

});
```

Now your probably thinking why don't I just do this...

```
$("a.gallery-thumb").fancybox({

    afterLoad   : function() {

        FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info) {

            var scrollPosition = info.scrollTop;

            $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');   

        };            

    }

    afterShow    : function() { },
    onUpdate     : function() { }

});
```

OK - this works fine, but I need the `scrollPosition` variable in other fancybox callbacks like `afterShow` and `onUpdate`. But sure I can just repeat `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo` function... Not quite, I need the original generated value from when the gallery initial click was made.

So perhaps I have to do something like this, but I can't seem to get it to work, any ideas on how I can get the below script working?

```
$("a.gallery-thumb").on('click', function (){

    event.preventDefault(); /* I'm trying to stop the image opening by default before my fancybox function runs */

    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info) {

        var scrollPosition = info.scrollTop;

        $(this).attr('rel','fancybox-thumb').fancybox({

            onUpdate   : function() {

                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');

            },

            afterLoad   : function() {

                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');

            },

            afterShow    : function() {

                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');

            },

            onUpdate     : function() {

                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');

            }

        });

    });

});
```

See js fiddle here emulating my problem of the fancybox function not firing...

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/1631/][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just move the variable declaration up a level so it's in scope for the whole function? Like:

```
var scrollPosition = 0;
$("a.gallery-thumb").on('click', function (event){

    event.preventDefault(); /* I'm trying to stop the image opening by default before my fancybox function runs */
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info) {

        scrollPosition = info.scrollTop;
    });
    return false;
    }).each(function(){

        $(this).attr('rel','fancybox-thumb').fancybox({             
            onUpdate   : function() {   
                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');           
            },                          
            afterLoad   : function() {              
                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');            
        },
            afterShow    : function() {
                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');
            },
            onUpdate     : function() {
                $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+=' + scrollPosition + 'px');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I didnt know you could move variables. Thats cool. The problem is that the `.fancybox({` is not firing? I will make a fiddle. Thanks

Comment: Where a variable is declared (is one of the things, at least, that) determines its scope. Variables declared outside any functions are called global variables and are visible and modifiable by all functions (assuming they are mutable vars). Variables declared inside a function will persist and can be modified until the end of that function.

Comment: your fiddle doesn't include the fancybox script.

Comment: It does but it is broken - see this working one.. http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/1632/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/1634/ Weirdly, though, it's taking 2 clicks to work....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/1639/ is working. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510194/why-does-fancybox-require-two-clicks-activate. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hmmm that is strange but yeah that is doing the trick, how ever I can't get thumbnails to work?! Ahh. http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/1645/ not working. http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/1646/ working? I can't get my head round it.

Comment: Thanks for investigating that - I've been trying for ages to sort this :) Thought not the other problem with the thumbs, it just makes no sense. It's not rel attr that is the problem either.

Comment: It works! I dropped the code into my project and all worked great first time. Thanks for all your help and time. I'm guessing the helpers must have been a bug perhaps in jsFiddle.